# JavaScript only performs function based off onClick event once?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onclick

I am working on a program that will output XML code for easy copy + pasting.  I have check boxes set up and want the user to be able to check off certain values that will then output specific lines for the XML code.  The issue is once they click the button once it will not do it again.  Any ideas why?

Relevant JavaScript:

```
function add() {
if (document.getElementById("POTBDetail").checked) {
                if (document.getElementById("STT").checked) {       
                    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<xsl:variable name="POSalesTaxTotalVar" select="\'Y\'"/> \n';
                }
                else {
                    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<xsl:variable name="POSalesTaxTotalVar" select="\'N\'"/> \n';
                }
                //if they want discount total var showing
                if (document.getElementById("DT").checked) {        
                    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<xsl:variable name="PODiscountTotalVar" select="\'Y\'"/> \n';
                }
                else {
                    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<xsl:variable name="PODiscountTotalVar" select="\'N\'"/> \n';
                }
                //if they want credit total var showing
                if (document.getElementById("CT").checked) {        
                    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<xsl:variable name="POCreditTotalVar" select="\'Y\'"/> \n';
                }
                else {
                    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<xsl:variable name="POCreditTotalVar" select="\'N\'"/> \n';
                }
                //if they want freight total var showing
                if (document.getElementById("FT").checked) {        
                    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<xsl:variable name="POFreightTotalVar" select="\'Y\'"/> \n';
                }
                else {
                    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<xsl:variable name="POFreightTotalVar" select="\'N\'"/> \n';
                }
                //if they want freight total var showing
                if (document.getElementById("POLIT").checked) {     
                    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<xsl:variable name="POExtTotalVar" select="\'Y\'"/> \n';
                }
                else {
                    TheTextBox.value = TheTextBox.value + '<xsl:variable name="POExtTotalVar" select="\'N\'"/> \n';
                }
            }//end of if detail is checked
}//end of function
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<form name="input" method="get">
<h3>How do you want the information displayed in the Purchase Order Total Box at the
bottom of the page?</h3> 
<input type="checkbox" name="POTBDetail" id = "POTBDetail" value="Detail">Detail (Please check off all items you want displayed in the box) See Ply 1 – G of template for printed example<br>
<input type="checkbox" style = "margin-left:5em" name="POLIT" id = "POLIT" value="PO Line Item Total">PO Line Item Total<br>
<input type="checkbox" style = "margin-left:5em" name="CT" id = "CT" value="Credit Total">Credit Total<br>
<input type="checkbox" style = "margin-left:5em" name="STT" id = "STT" value="STT">Sales Tax Total<br>
<input type="checkbox" style = "margin-left:5em" name="DT" id = "DT" value="Discount Total">Discount Total<br>
<input type="checkbox" style = "margin-left:5em" name="FT" id = "FT" value="Freight Total">Freight Total<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="POTBTotal" id = "POTBTotal" value="Total">Show PO Total Only, no Detail Items See Ply 3 – C of template for printed example<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="POTBNone" id = "POTBNone" value="None">None – I don’t require a PO Total Box on this copy of the PO<br>
<h3></h3> 

<input type="button" value = "convert to text!" id = "button" onClick = "add()"/>
</br>
<textarea id = "output" style = "width:90%;height:40%;" onClick = "this.select();"></textarea>
</form>
```

As a side note it does work just as intended once, just only once.  Thanks to all who help!

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: Are there any errors appear in console when you click the button?

Comment: Yeah, according to Chrome there are none

Answer (score 0):

You weren't clearing the output at the beginning of the function, so it would just keep adding on top of the existing text.

You can use `variable +=` instead of `variable = variable +`. You can also utilize objects, arrays, a loop, some type conversion, and an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) to greatly simplify the logic.

```js
var add = (function(){
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var detail = document.getElementById("POTBDetail");
    var checkboxes = {
        POSalesTaxTotalVar: document.getElementById("STT"),
        PODiscountTotalVar: document.getElementById("DT"),
        POCreditTotalVar:   document.getElementById("CT"),
        POFreightTotalVar:  document.getElementById("FT"),
        POExtTotalVar:      document.getElementById("POLIT")
    }, keys = Object.keys(checkboxes);
    var select = ['N','Y'];
    return function() {
        output.value = '';
        if (!detail.checked) return;
        for(var i in keys) {
            var key = keys[i]
            var sel = select[+checkboxes[key].checked];
            output.value += '<xsl:variable name="' + key + '" select="\'' + sel + '\'"/> \n';
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<form name="input" method="get">
    <h3>How do you want the information displayed in the Purchase Order Total Box at the
bottom of the page?</h3> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="POTBDetail" id="POTBDetail" value="Detail">Detail (Please check off all items you want displayed in the box) See Ply 1 – G of template for printed example<br>
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left:5em" name="POLIT" id="POLIT" value="PO Line Item Total">PO Line Item Total<br>
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left:5em" name="CT" id="CT" value="Credit Total">Credit Total<br>
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left:5em" name="STT" id="STT" value="STT">Sales Tax Total<br>
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left:5em" name="DT" id="DT" value="Discount Total">Discount Total<br>
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin-left:5em" name="FT" id="FT" value="Freight Total">Freight Total<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="POTBTotal" id="POTBTotal" value="Total">Show PO Total Only, no Detail Items See Ply 3 – C of template for printed example<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="POTBNone" id="POTBNone" value="None">None – I don’t require a PO Total Box on this copy of the PO<br>
    <input type="button" value="convert to text!" id="button" onClick="add()" /><br>
    <textarea id="output" style="width:90%;height:40%;" onClick="this.select();"></textarea>
</form>
```